# SQL MariaDB apply regex to column

Tags: sql, regex, database, mariadb

I'm moving a couple operations from my backend services to the database. I'm currently creating a view to transform a couple tables into a single table. As an example, the user table has one row per user, and the user meta table has one row per meta field per user, so each user can have multiple meta fields, hence why I'd like to combine this into a single table through a view.

Sidenote, `DBUser` has been redacted.

```sql
create definer = DBUser@`%` view mm_users as
select `DBUser`.`wp_users`.`ID`                                                                             AS `id`,
       `DBUser`.`wp_users`.`user_login`                                                                     AS `login`,
       `DBUser`.`wp_users`.`user_email`                                                                     AS `email`,
       max(if(`DBUser`.`wp_usermeta`.`meta_key` = 'nickname',
              `DBUser`.`wp_usermeta`.`meta_value`,
              NULL))                                                                                        AS `nickname`,
       max(if(`DBUser`.`wp_usermeta`.`meta_key` = 'first_name',
              `DBUser`.`wp_usermeta`.`meta_value`,
              NULL))                                                                                        AS `first_name`,
       max(if(`DBUser`.`wp_usermeta`.`meta_key` = 'last_name',
              `DBUser`.`wp_usermeta`.`meta_value`,
              NULL))                                                                                        AS `last_name`,
       max(if(`DBUser`.`wp_usermeta`.`meta_key` = 'user-jahrgangsstufe',
              `DBUser`.`wp_usermeta`.`meta_value`, NULL))                                                   AS `class`,
       max(case
               when `DBUser`.`wp_usermeta`.`meta_key` = 'user-schule'
                   then `DBUser`.`wp_usermeta`.`meta_value` end)                                            AS `school`,
       case
           when `DBUser`.`wp_usermeta`.`meta_key` = 'je_data_store_angebote-favoriten'
               then regexp_replace(`DBUser`.`wp_usermeta`.`meta_value`, 's:4:"([0-9]{1,4})"',
                                   '\\1') end                                                               AS `favorites`,
       max(case
               when `DBUser`.`wp_usermeta`.`meta_key` = 'wp_capabilities' then regexp_replace(
                       `DBUser`.`wp_usermeta`.`meta_value`,
                       '^a:1:{s:[0-9]+:"(subscriber|editor|contributor|administrator)";b:1;}$', '\\1') end) AS `role`
from (`DBUser`.`wp_users` left join `DBUser`.`wp_usermeta`
      on (`DBUser`.`wp_users`.`ID` = `DBUser`.`wp_usermeta`.`user_id`))
where `DBUser`.`wp_usermeta`.`meta_key` in
      ('nickname', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'wp_capabilities', 'user-jahrgangsstufe', 'user-schule',
       'je_data_store_angebote-favoriten')
group by `DBUser`.`wp_users`.`ID`;
```

Everything works apart from transforming the `je_data_store_angebote-favoriten` metadata. For clarification, this meta value is a serialized PHP string with 0 to 5 values, a couple examples:

```php
a:0:{}
a:1:{i:0;s:4:"3131";}
a:2:{i:0;s:4:"2535";i:1;s:4:"2539";}
a:3:{i:0;s:4:"3119";i:1;s:4:"3086";i:2;s:4:"2615";}
a:4:{i:0;s:4:"2950";i:1;s:4:"3185";i:2;s:4:"2478";i:3;s:4:"2568";}
a:5:{i:0;s:4:"3025";i:1;s:4:"3032";i:2;s:4:"3202";i:3;s:4:"2550";i:4;s:4:"3080";}
a:5:{i:0;s:4:"25";i:1;s:4:"7";i:2;s:4:"33556";i:3;s:4:"4597";i:4;s:4:"21594";}
```

I've put `s:4:"([0-9]{1,4})"` into https://regex101.com/ and it matches everything I need it to, but when creating this view, the favourites column is `null` for all users. What gives? I can apply a regex pattern to get the role of the user, why can't I do the same to get the favourites of a user?

Comment: the problem, besides that your code is not valid, is that you forgot then MAX around the hole cASE WHEN

Comment: Are you really trying to implement PHP `unserialize()` in a MySQL view?

Comment: @nbk How is my code not valid? I'm not getting any errors when running it. What am I missing? From my understanding, enclosing the whole ordeal in a MAX would result in only one value being displayed, but I want all values, separated by commas.

Comment: @Barmar I have no control over the data generation / database design, so there's nothing I can do in that department.

Comment: @MilanDierick your code works as intended https://dbfiddle.uk/uOCjW-nQ  as you get NULL you have 2 possibilities once the is no such meta key maybe typo, or you get multiple  values, if MAX is not what you need make a GROUP_CONCAT

Comment: @nbk Thank you for that snippet! Here's what I've got so far: https://dbfiddle.uk/cKTk79-S To reiterate, I'd like to get all values from that serialized PHP array, not just the first. Currently, my regex pattern fails to match the empty array case, and ideally I'd like to have the numbers be separated by commas (which is the case at the moment), but not have that leading comma there. I'm scratching my head a bit as to how I can achieve that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was a tricky one, but as i thought you can use `GROUP_CONCAT`

to get rid of the empty one, you can do as you already have done

```
CREATE TABLE tex
    (`val` varchar(81))
;
    
INSERT INTO tex
    (`val`)
VALUES
    ('a:0:{}'),
    ('a:1:{i:0;s:4:"3131";}'),
    ('a:2:{i:0;s:4:"2535";i:1;s:4:"2539";}'),
    ('a:3:{i:0;s:4:"3119";i:1;s:4:"3086";i:2;s:4:"2615";}'),
    ('a:4:{i:0;s:4:"2950";i:1;s:4:"3185";i:2;s:4:"2478";i:3;s:4:"2568";}'),
    ('a:5:{i:0;s:4:"3025";i:1;s:4:"3032";i:2;s:4:"3202";i:3;s:4:"2550";i:4;s:4:"3080";}'),
    ('a:5:{i:0;s:4:"25";i:1;s:4:"7";i:2;s:4:"33556";i:3;s:4:"4597";i:4;s:4:"21594";}')
;
```

> ```
> Records: 7  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE(val, '^a:\\d+:\\{\\\}|a:\\d+:\\{i:\\d+;s:\\d+:"|";i:\\d+;s:\\d+:"|";\\}$', ','),2) SEPARATOR  "") AS string_values
FROM
  tex;
```

| string_values |
| --- |
| 3131,2535,2539,3119,3086,2615,2950,3185,2478,2568,3025,3032,3202,2550,3080,25,7,33556,4597,21594, |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/XJdzlPF2)